# Transition boundary condition

Tags: electromagnetism, computational-physics, maxwell-equations, photonics

I am reading about the "Transition Boundary Condition" at [this link](https://doc.comsol.com/5.5/doc/com.comsol.help.acdc/acdc_ug_magnetic_fields.08.043.html).

Can someone please explain where the following boundary conditions come from?

$$J_{s1} = \frac{Z_s E_{t1} - Z_T E_{t2}}{Z_S^2 - Z_T^2} \\
J_{s2} = \frac{Z_s E_{t2} - Z_T E_{t1}}{Z_S^2 - Z_T^2} \\
Z_S = \frac{-i\omega \mu}{k} \frac{1}{\tan{(kd)}} \\
Z_T = \frac{-i\omega \mu}{k} \frac{1}{\sin{(kd)}} \\
k = \omega \sqrt{(\epsilon + (\sigma/i\omega)) \mu}$$

where $T$ and $S$ stand for "transfer" and "surface" respectively and $1,2$ stand for different sides of the layer. I am trying to model the interface between a medium with $\epsilon, \mu > 0$ and a medium with $\epsilon, \mu < 0$ (negative index material), and it seems like this boundary condition is needed in the simulation, but I don't understand why.

It is used in COMSOL to "change the flux across a boundary" but I don't understand where these equations are coming from. Any helpful references would be greatly appreciated too!

Comment: We prefer questions to be self-contained and use links as supplemental material. Could you transcribe the equations (and whatever text around it you think relevant) as well as describe what it is you are modeling, rather than having us guess?

Comment: Many books on electrodynamics contain sections on boundary conditions. For example, Jackson *Classical Electrodynamics* in the introduction I.5. Try to go through these first, I would suggest